# Crystal report Memo field characters limit

Tags: crystal-reports, rtf, truncated

I`m using Crystal Reports Version 14.1.1.1036 to show an RTF Field stored in my SQL server as nvarchar(max), the problem is that my nvarchar(max) is interpreted as a Memo Field in Crystal Reports, only part of my data is being previewed (text is being truncated). Field's property is set to "Can Grow" with 0 as a Maximum number of lines. thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, it turned out that Crystal Report have this fault by design, and there is no means to fix it. The maximum size of a text field is set to 64KB at maximum, and the only way to resolve this is by String Splitting very large fields.
Check [this post](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3219877) for more information.

Comment: Tried that, but with no avail